# When click of radio button, show text input control, trying to input text shuts app down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to type text in an text input control, after selecting a radio button to display the div that the control is in. The problem I am having is after clicking the correct radio button and showing the div with the text box control is in, to type the information the app closes. I am doing this in Visual Studio. My HTML and Jquery code is below.

```
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7">
          <label for="radio1">
               <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="optGiftCardRadio" value="email">Send my Gift Card by Email.
          </label>
          <div id="One" style="display:none">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                       <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="email">Email Address:<span style="color:red" class="required"> *</span></label>
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
                       </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                       <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="confirmEmail">Confirm Email Address:<span style="color:red" class="required"> *</span></label>
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="confirmEmail" name="confirmEmail">
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
          </div>                             
          <label for="radio2">
               <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="optGiftCardRadio" value="regularMail">Send my Gift Card by U.S. Mail.
          </label>
          <div id="Two" style="display: none;">
               You elect to recieve a physical Gift Card in the mail at the mailing addres you provided.
          </div>                             
      </div>
```

And here is the Jquery

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "email") {
        $("#One").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#One").hide();
    }

    if ($(this).val() == "regularMail") {
        $("#Two").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#Two").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean "the app closes"?

Comment: I've made a Fiddle here and see no issue with the code. http://jsfiddle.net/ag0fetzx/

Comment: It is working now, don't know why but it is, thanks everyone.